# Reduce size of pyqt5 html-viewer application build with pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qwebengineview

I have a small webview application:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import sys

class MyWebViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        webview = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(webview)
        webview.setHtml("<html><body><H1>test</h1></body></html>")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = MyWebViewer()
    m.show()
    app.exec()
```

The problem is that when I build it with pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --noconsole test_application.py
```

the size of the application becomes very large (164mb) and Qt5WebEngineCore.dll comprise 69mb alone.

I use a clean python installation with only the neccessary modules:

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

altgraph (0.15)
future (0.16.0)
macholib (1.9)
pefile (2017.11.5)
pip (9.0.1)
PyInstaller (3.3.1)
pypiwin32 (223)
PyQt5 (5.10.1)
pywin32 (223)
setuptools (28.8.0)
sip (4.19.8)
```

The viewer is intended to show sphinx-generated html documentation. How can I reduce the size of the application.

Comment: [`QTextEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) can display a large subset of html. You might be able to use it instead to eliminate the `QWebEngine` dependency.

Comment: @user3419537. It's actually only a [very limited subset](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html). It's unlikely that it will render sphinx docs correctly.

Comment: Are you building the executable from an Anaconda environment? If so, some users have reported that their executable file size can be reduced by running PyInstaller from a virtual environment instead -
 with Python installed from source and only including minimally necessary packages.

Comment: @apogalacticon I am running PyInstaller from a minimal virtual envirronment made from a clean standard python installation