# How to reduce exe file size in pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to develop .exe file from my python script , but its size is more than 715MB , even i am using virtual environment for developing but still size is very big.

These libraries i am using in my script:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import configparser
```

Steps for developing .exe

```
1）pip install virtualenv  #install virtualenv

2）virtualenv name_env  #creat a virtualenv

3）pip install your packages in  new virtualenv

4）cmd and activate

5）cd to the dir of python script

4）pyinstaller -w -F  mainscript.py
```

Anyone can help to figure out where i am making mistake

normally this app should be 42MB or less than 50MB

but here size is 600MB+

Comment: I have used `pyi-archive_viewer` to see what is being included in the exe. Then use `excludes` in the `.spec` file to exclude the ones not needed from the exe.

Comment: I saved 400MB, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722188/tutorial-for-installing-numpy-with-openblas-on-windows/67954011#67954011. I cannot answer because a moderator deleted it, even if the two questions are on a total different topic...

Answer (score 0):

A large contribution is probably due to Qt (used by `matplotlib`) and [MKL](https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-optimizations/index.html) (used by `numpy`).

See for example:

- [Reduce size of pyqt5 html-viewer application build with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49045142)
- [size of executable using pyinstaller and numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47769904).

Using [OpenBlas](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS) instead of MKL can help.

To illustrate the difference, I built a simple example application with `matplotlib/Qt` and `numpy` using two different [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) environments, on **Windows** 10: one using MKL, the other using openblas, as specified in the YAML files below.

The resulting executable sizes were:

- mkl: 312 MB
- openblas: 100 MB

The environments can be created using `conda env create -f <filename>`.

MKL environment (also see [this discussion](https://github.com/conda-forge/numpy-feedstock/issues/153)):

```yaml
name: mkl
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - matplotlib
  - pyinstaller
```

Openblas environment (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61220181) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67954011)):

```yaml
name: openblas
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - conda-forge::blas=*=openblas
  - conda-forge::matplotlib
  - pyinstaller
```

Example application:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.arange(0, 10 * np.pi, 0.1)
    y = np.sin(x)
    dot_product = np.dot(y, y.T)  # just some matrix operation
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.title(dot_product)
    plt.show()
```

Built using: `pyinstaller --clean -w -F main.py`